# How to call a predefined method from struts2 tags in jsp

Tags: java, google-app-engine, struts2

I want to create an object for UserService(app engine User service) class in my jsp using struts tags and call it's createLoginURL(req.getRequestURI()) method.

How can I do it? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Should I create a custom tag library and call an appropriate method using custom tags in jsp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should all be handled in an action (or utility class), not in JSP.

Get an instance of `UserService` in the action. The action should implement [`ServletRequestAware`](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3.1/docs/how-can-we-access-the-httpservletrequest.html) since it needs to call a method on the request (normally this is discouraged as it ties the action to the servlet spec).

Save the results of `userService.createLoginURL(req.getRequestURI())` method as an action property and render it in the JSP.

The only thing that should happen in the JSP is the rendering of that string as a link.

Comment: Hi @DaveNewton, thanks for you valuable reply. I can do it that way, but is there any way to this in the jsp? Why am I asking is because, in the very first page, i.e. the index page, I have to generate a link to login page.

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya You'd do it the exact same way, but in the JSP. But in an S2 app you really shouldn't see any JSP pages; any welcome pages should either redirect to an action, or the container should be configured to allow non-file/servlet resources as welcome files (don't know if that's possible in GAE).

Comment: I did not understand. Can you please tell in detail? Thanks in advance

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya It's difficult to be too much more details--I gave you the exact steps to follow; it's the exact same steps you'd follow inside a scriptlet, except that you don't need to implement `ServletRequestAware`, because you have direct access to the request. It's for a single page--making it into a tag would be pointless.

Comment: Ok I will do as you said. What I am thinking is to create a index.jsp page which has a link "login here". This will execute an action. In that action I would redirect the user again using the `request.sendredirect(createLoginURL(request.getRequestURI()))` method. But I dint understand "You dont need to implement `ServletRequestAware`. How can I get the request uri then?

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya JSPs have an implicit request object already. You left out the `UserService` instance in the above code.

Comment: I am not supposed to use scriptlets. That is where the problem came

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya And normally you shouldn't, but it's just not worth the effort to make a tag for a single page. Tags exist for re-use. Make a JSP-based custom tag, put the scriptlet in there, and don't tell anybody.